# Disable the "a" attribute underline?

Tags: html, css

I was wondering how you would disable to underline on the "a" attribute, for href's. I find it annoying, and I was wondering if there was a bit of code I could add to my .css to change it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

simply set `a {text-decoration:none}`

see in action:

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none
}
```

```html
<a href="#">No Underline</a>
```

**EDIT** <sub><sub>(I am editing this to whoever downvote it, because that could be the only reason for)</sub></sub>

In case you have multiple `a`'s and some of them don't have  the attribute `href` then you can target the `href` like this:

```css
/*demo */

div {
  border: dotted lightblue;
  margin: 10px;
  font-size:30px
}
a {
  display: block;
}
/*in action*/
div:last-of-type a[href] {
  text-decoration: none
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a>Without href doesn't make it a link</a>
  <a href="#">Link with Underline</a>
</div>
<div>
  <a>Without href doesn't make it a link</a>
  <a href="#">Link Without Underline</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple google search provides this very easy....

```
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```